# Assigning listItems to single string by comma separated

Tags: c#, asp.net, join, listitem

I have a `listItems` which I want to assign to a string. SO I tried like below

```
for (int i = 0; i < LocationDetails.Count; i++)
{
    strMaintZone = String.Join(",", LocationDetails[i].LocationID);
}
```

But it is not getting assigned and it takes the last value. How do I assign the value to the string.

Comment: @PeterB: `LocationDetails` has values like `List<UMSLocationDetails> lstUMSLocationDetails` which has 2 parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ can be helpful here. You should pass `IEnumerable<string>` to `string.Join` method. The `IEnumerable<string>` can be made by LINQ `Select` clause.

```
strMaintZone = string.Join(",", LocationDetails.Select(item => item.LocationID));
```

In your example problem is that you every time override the value of `strMaintZone`, and as a result you will have only the last element.

Comment: can we do it without loop ??

Comment: yes you dont need to take loop. just pass your collection to String.Join

Comment: yes tried with that too and its working perfectly fine.. what is `Select` here for ?? any specific reason

Comment: Yup, take a look at `System.Linq` namespace

Comment: `Select` is a projection, you take one element from original collection and project it as another element.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to loop through your list.
just pass collection to second argument of String.Join just like below:

```
  strMaintZone = String.Join(",", LocationDetails.Select(x=>x.LocationID));
```

LocationDetails.Select(x=>x.LocationID) returns collection of LocationIDs("1","2"..) which is passed to String.Join() second argument.